# Generate and download tsv from a website (with python)

Tags: python, html, parsing, web, download

I have [this website](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/interpro/protein/UniProt/Q9BXF6/entry/InterPro/#table) and want to write a script which can execute a code which gives the same output as clicking on 'Export' -> 'Generate tsv' -> Wait to generate -> 'Download'.
The endgoal is to use this for a list of approx. 1700 proteins which I have  in .txt (so extract a protein, in this case 'Q9BXF6' and put it in the url: https://www.ebi.ac.uk/interpro/protein/UniProt/Q9BXF6/entry/InterPro/#table) and download all results in .tsv files.

I tried inspecting the 'Export' button but the sourcecode wasn't illuminating (or I didn't know where to look). I also tried this:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.ebi.ac.uk/interpro/protein/UniProt/Q9BXF6/entry/InterPro/#table')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
```

to locate what I need but it outputs a bunch of characters that I can't really understand.
I also tried downloading the whole page just like it is with the urllib library:
with

```
myurl = 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/interpro/protein/UniProt/Q9BXF6/entry/InterPro/#table'
urllib.request.urlopen() as f:
          html = f.read().decode('utf-8')
```

or

```
urllib.urlretrieve (myurl, 'interpro.txt') # although this didn't work
```

It seems as if all content is written somewhere else and refered to and everything I've tried outputs something stupid, but I don't know anything about html and am really new to python (I only use R).

Comment: They've been really nice to have actually even given you the entire script of how you could do so. Have you checked [here](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/interpro/result/download/#/entry/InterPro/protein/UniProt/Q9BXF6/|tsv)?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you can use the `URL` of the following element to retrieve the protein value that you require for the next problem.

```
href="blob:https://www.ebi.ac.uk/806960aa-720c-4958-9392-f242adee627b"
```

The `URL` is set to the `href` tag which you can then use it to make the request to download the file. You can also obtain this by right-clicking on the download button for `TSV` and clicking `Inspect-Element` you will then be able to see the presence of this `href` tag.

Following that, download by doing e.g.

```
import urllib.request

url = 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/806960aa-720c-4958-9392-f242adee627b'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, '/Users/abc/Downloads/file.tsv') # any dir to save

with open("/Users/abc/Downloads/file.tsv") as file_in:
    for line in file_in:
        #here make your calls for your second problem.
```

You can also use a `Web-Automator` such as selenium to gracefully solve this problem. If the latter is of interest do look into it - it's not hard.

Comment: Thanks, that really helps! I found everything you described. However, that's the link only after clicking generate. Is there a way to get to that with another link? The \href when the button is still generate doesn't lead to the button converting to a 'download'. [It leads to another page for which the tsv file which can be downloaded is not the same as the tsv from the original page]

Comment: Upon another look, it seems as though the`url` obtained from the site is dynamically generated and is only valid for a pre-set time - you can visit that now and check that it is no longer valid. In order to solve this, you have to use an automator such as Selenium since the request module cannot do the job of this task. I would recommend starting with Documentation of Selenium and you work your way through it to solve the problem. The process of selenium will involve visiting the page, clicking the Generate button, getting the required url, downloading the file, etc.